# JS Slide Background Image based on Click event on thumbnail Problem

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question on JS project I am doing. I don't know the reason why the JS logic is not working. Trying to implement a sliding image based on thumbnail selected. Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19aIf.png)

[I have attached my VS code and Website result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THXWV.png)

product.js

```js
const productImages = document.querySelectorAll(".product-images img"); // selecting all image thumbs
const productImageSlide = document.querySelector(".image-slider"); // seclecting image slider element

let activeImageSlide = 0; // default slider image

productImages.forEach((item, i) => {
  // loopinh through each image thumb
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // adding click event to each image thumbnail
    productImages[activeImageSlide].classList.remove("active"); // removing active class from current image thumb
    item.classList.add("active"); // adding active class to the current or clicked image thumb
    productImageSlide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${item.src}')`; // setting up image slider's background image
    activeImageSlide = i; // updating the image slider variable to track current thumb
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="product.css" />
    <script src="product.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="product-details">
      <div class="image-slider">
        <div class="product-images">
          <img src="Images/33.png" class="active" alt="" />
          <img src="Images/44.png" alt="" />
          <img src="Images/55.png" alt="" />
          <img src="Images/6.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please embed the code as text and the image.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have embedded the codes now.

Answer (score 0):

Your interactive code runs fine: once you click on a thumbnail everything updates. Click the images in the example below to see the background change:

```js
const productImages = document.querySelectorAll(".product-images img"); // selecting all image thumbs
const productImageSlide = document.querySelector(".image-slider"); // seclecting image slider element

let activeImageSlide = 0; 
productImages.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    item.classList.add("active");
    productImageSlide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${item.src}')`;
    activeImageSlide = i;
  });
});
```

```css
.image-slider {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: grey;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}

img.active {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="product-details">
  <div class="image-slider">
    <div class="product-images">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/100" class="active" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/100" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/100" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/40/100" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

However, the initial state doesn't match what's expected. You set the `active` class, but you never copy over the active image's src to the parent.

---

An easy fix would be to add this line outside of the foreach:

```js
productImageSlide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${productImages[activeImageSlide].src}')`;
```

Check out the example below to see the correctly initialized background

```js
const productImages = document.querySelectorAll(".product-images img"); // selecting all image thumbs
const productImageSlide = document.querySelector(".image-slider"); // seclecting image slider element

let activeImageSlide = 0; 
productImages.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    item.classList.add("active");
    productImageSlide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${item.src}')`;
    activeImageSlide = i;
  });
});

productImageSlide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${productImages[activeImageSlide].src}')`;
```

```css
.image-slider {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: grey;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}

img.active {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="product-details">
  <div class="image-slider">
    <div class="product-images">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/100" class="active" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/100" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/100" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/40/100" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

If you don't like the repetition, you could separate the click-handling logic from the render logic.

The example below has a single `render` function that takes the index of the active image and ensures everything displays correctly.

The click handler calls `render` with the clicked image's index. To initialize the page, you call `render(0)`.

```js
const productImages = document.querySelectorAll(".product-images img"); // selecting all image thumbs
const productImageSlide = document.querySelector(".image-slider"); // seclecting image slider element


// How to render the state
const render = activeImageIndex => {
  productImages.forEach(img => img.classList.remove("active"));
  productImages[activeImageIndex].classList.add("active");
  productImageSlide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${productImages[activeImageIndex].src}')`;
}

// How to handle clicks
const onClick = (item, i) => {
  render(i);
}


// Attach listeners
productImages.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    onClick(item, i);
  });
});

// Render initial state
render(0);
```

```css
.image-slider {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: grey;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}

img.active {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="product-details">
  <div class="image-slider">
    <div class="product-images">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/100" class="active" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/100" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/100" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/40/100" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow Very Elaborate and thorough answer. It makes me happy there are people like you in Computer Science who are willing to help little beginners like me. Thank you and Happy new year.